# Writing Numbers to a text file - batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

This should be a simple one and I am dissapointed with myself but cant for the life of me find a solution! I am trying to write the number 1 to a text file in a BAT script. If I do the below it works but leaves a trailing space after the number which I cannot have. I know you can remove the trailing space by deleting the space between the 1 and the > (this works with letters) but with numbers all of a sudden I get a message saying - ECHO is OFF.

```
ECHO 1 > mytextfile.txt
*This works but leaves a trailing space*

ECHO 1> mytextfile.txt
*This gives me an error saying ECHO is OFF*
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `echo 1> myTextFile.txt` will not echo `1`, instead the echo command is empty and the redirection goes to stream 1.

You could simply move the redirection to the front.

```
>mytextfile.txt echo 1
```

Comment: Now that's what I call a hidden feature. I never knew you can put that to the front as well.

Comment: It's allowed to put it somewhere in the line, even `echo >mytextfile.txt 1` is allowed (but then you get a leading space)

Comment: This works great, good to see others learning from my inexperience with Bat files too! Cheers guys

Answer (score 5):

`1>` is a special command. Use `(ECHO 1) > mytextfile.txt` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`echo.1>mytextfile.txt` should work as well.

Comment: But that's only **luck**! If you try to write `3 2 1` the same way with `echo.3 2 1>mytextfile.txt` it fails