# When I create a Loadable save file it adds space in batch! Why is this so?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The only problem I have is when it comes to numbers in batch files, say we're writing them to a save file to load up later with the following command `echo Variable=%Var% >>Variable.bat`.

Now that is all cool but here is a few things I noticed!

First of all if the `%Var%` is a number then I can't write `%Var%>>` because without that space then it just gets written as `Variable=` and this is not matter the number when I load it up now if I can't have the no spacing then I must have the spacing and it goes as follows `Variable=%Var%` lets say `%Var%` is 7 for instance I will put brackets around it to show what happens on each save and each load the underscore will show spaces `(Variable=7_) (Variable=7__) (Variable=7___) (Variable=7____)`

Now I will show you some code that shows this in action and I will purposely post words after the numbers so you will see the words actually shifting over every time you view it in Prompt screen!

Watch when you run this, the space keeps adding up and I have no clue how to remove the space.

## Gruff.Bat

```
@echo off
color 0D
title Something
echo @echo off>blah.bat
echo color 0D>>blah.bat
echo title Something>>blah.bat
echo set Character=Monstrous Bunny>>blah.bat
echo set Name=BBQ Chips>>blah.bat
echo set ID=%Random% >>blah.bat
echo set LV=5 >>blah.bat
echo set Money=1234567890 >>blah.bat
echo set Rings=3 >>blah.bat
echo set Weapons=21 >>blah.bat
echo set Armors=14 >>blah.bat
echo set Runes=2 >>blah.bat
echo set HP=100 >>blah.bat
echo set ATK=25 >>blah.bat
echo set DEF=5 >>blah.bat
echo set ArmorPen=10 >>blah.bat
echo set BaseDEF=5 >>blah.bat
echo set Heal=10 >>blah.bat
echo set Gold=298736 >>blah.bat
echo set STAM=10 >>blah.bat
echo set Mana=15 >>blah.bat
echo set Spells=2 >>blah.bat
echo set Counter=0 >>blah.bat
echo Call Gruff2.bat>>blah.bat
Set /a Counter+=1
Start blah.bat
exit
```

## Gruff2.Bat

```
@echo off
color 0D
title Character Viewer
cls
echo ID#%ID% Level %LV% %Character% %Name%
echo.
echo STATS
echo %HP% HP, %ATK% Attack, %DEF% Defense, %STAM% Stamina, %Mana% Mana
echo.
echo OTHER STATS
echo %ArmorPen% Armor Penetration, %BaseDEF% Base Defense
echo.
echo %Money% Money, %Gold% Gold
echo %Rings% Rings, %Runes% Runes, %Weapons% Weapons, %Armors% Armors
echo.
echo SPECIAL ABILITIES
echo %Heal% Pts of Heal per Quarter Minute, %Spells% Spells Known
echo You Have Saved The Game %Counter% Times!
echo @echo off>blah.bat
echo color 0D>>blah.bat
echo title Something>>blah.bat
echo set Character=%Character%>>blah.bat
echo set Name=%Name%>>blah.bat
echo set ID=%ID% >>blah.bat
echo set LV=%LV% >>blah.bat
echo set Money=%Money% >>blah.bat
echo set Rings=%Rings% >>blah.bat
echo set Weapons=%Weapons% >>blah.bat
echo set Armors=%Armors% >>blah.bat
echo set Runes=%Rings% >>blah.bat
echo set HP=%HP% >>blah.bat
echo set ATK=%ATK% >>blah.bat
echo set DEF=%DEF% >>blah.bat
echo set ArmorPen=%ArmorPen% >>blah.bat
echo set BaseDEF=%BaseDEF% >>blah.bat
echo set Heal=%Heal% >>blah.bat
echo set Gold=%Gold% >>blah.bat
echo set STAM=%STAM% >>blah.bat
echo set Mana=%Mana% >>blah.bat
echo set Spells=%Spells% >>blah.bat
echo set Counter=%Counter% >>blah.bat
echo Call Gruff2.bat>>blah.bat
Set /a Counter+=1
pause
Call blah.bat
```

Comment: My eyes..... Please put the code in code sample blocks use ctrl+k.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Numbers to a text file - batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225683/writing-numbers-to-a-text-file-batch-file)

Comment: Change syntax `echo set LV=5 >>blah.bat` to `>>blah.bat echo set LV=5`; otherwise, the space before `>>` is `echoed` and redirected too; (do **not** use this: `echo set LV=5>>blah.bat` (space removed, but `5>>` means specifying the redirection handle -- see [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)))...

Comment: not only my eyes hurt because of so many blank lines but my head spins because the 5-line sentence and I still can't get what you say

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
:: ___________________________________________________________________________

:: Gruff.Bat
:: ___________________________________________________________________________

@echo off
color 0D
title Something

>blah.bat (
    echo @echo off
    echo color 0D
    echo title Something
    echo set Character=Monstrous Bunny
    echo set Name=BBQ Chips
    echo set ID=%Random%
    echo set LV=5
    echo set Money=1234567890
    echo set Rings=3
    echo set Weapons=21
    echo set Armors=14
    echo set Runes=2
    echo set HP=100
    echo set ATK=25
    echo set DEF=5
    echo set ArmorPen=10
    echo set BaseDEF=5
    echo set Heal=10
    echo set Gold=298736
    echo set STAM=10
    echo set Mana=15
    echo set Spells=2
    echo set Counter=0
    echo Call Gruff2.bat
)
Set /a Counter+=1
Start blah.bat
exit

:: ___________________________________________________________________________

:: Gruff2.Bat
:: ___________________________________________________________________________

@echo off
color 0D
title Character Viewer
cls
echo ID#%ID% Level %LV% %Character% %Name%
echo.
echo STATS
echo %HP% HP, %ATK% Attack, %DEF% Defense, %STAM% Stamina, %Mana% Mana
echo.
echo OTHER STATS
echo %ArmorPen% Armor Penetration, %BaseDEF% Base Defense
echo.
echo %Money% Money, %Gold% Gold
echo %Rings% Rings, %Runes% Runes, %Weapons% Weapons, %Armors% Armors
echo.
echo SPECIAL ABILITIES
echo %Heal% Pts of Heal per Quarter Minute, %Spells% Spells Known
echo You Have Saved The Game %Counter% Times!

>blah.bat (
    echo @echo off
    echo color 0D
    echo title Something
    echo set Character=%Character%
    echo set Name=%Name%
    echo set ID=%ID%
    echo set LV=%LV%
    echo set Money=%Money%
    echo set Rings=%Rings%
    echo set Weapons=%Weapons%
    echo set Armors=%Armors%
    echo set Runes=%Rings%
    echo set HP=%HP%
    echo set ATK=%ATK%
    echo set DEF=%DEF%
    echo set ArmorPen=%ArmorPen%
    echo set BaseDEF=%BaseDEF%
    echo set Heal=%Heal%
    echo set Gold=%Gold%
    echo set STAM=%STAM%
    echo set Mana=%Mana%
    echo set Spells=%Spells%
    echo set Counter=%Counter%
    echo Call Gruff2.bat
)
Set /a Counter+=1
pause
Call blah.bat
```

Comment: are you aware, that this *still*  adds spaces to most ot the lines? (they are still part of the code)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way would be to change all the `set` commands to `set /a` which will cause the spaces to be ignored.

If you are loading/unloading a defined set of variables, then an easy trick is to name each variable that needs to be saved/reloaded with a common prefix like "#".

To save your data, the command is then

```
set #>filename
```

which places all of the variables starting `#` in the file *filename* in the format

```
#var1=value1
#var2=value2
```

and to reload,

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filename) do set "%%a"
```

which executes

```
set "#var1=value1"
set "#var2=value2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Compo, and everyone else we finally made this thing work as a team! I have already implemented some of what we did here in some of my games and everything seems to be working Just fine so far! :3 Meow! Hugzies to you all!

---

Gruff.Bat

---

```
@echo off
color 0D
title Something
>blah.bat (
    echo @echo off
    echo color 0D
    echo title Something
    echo set Character=Monstrous Bunny
    echo set Name=BBQ Chips
    echo set ID=%Random%
    echo set LV=5
    echo set Money=1234567890
    echo set Rings=3
    echo set Weapons=21
    echo set Armors=14
    echo set Runes=2
    echo set HP=100
    echo set ATK=25
    echo set DEF=5
    echo set ArmorPen=10
    echo set BaseDEF=5
    echo set Heal=10
    echo set Gold=298736
    echo set STAM=10
    echo set Mana=15
    echo set Spells=2
    echo set Counter=1
    echo Call Gruff2.bat
)
Start blah.bat
exit
```

---

Gruff2.Bat

---

```
@echo off
color 0D
title Character Viewer
cls
echo ID#%ID% Level %LV% %Character% %Name%
echo.
echo STATS
echo %HP% HP, %ATK% Attack, %DEF% Defense, %STAM% Stamina, %Mana% Mana
echo.
echo OTHER STATS
echo %ArmorPen% Armor Penetration, %BaseDEF% Base Defense
echo.
echo %Money% Money, %Gold% Gold
echo %Rings% Rings, %Runes% Runes, %Weapons% Weapons, %Armors% Armors
echo.
echo SPECIAL ABILITIES
echo %Heal% Pts of Heal per Quarter Minute, %Spells% Spells Known
echo You Have Saved The Game %Counter% Times!
set /a Counter+=1
>blah.bat (
    echo @echo off
    echo color 0D
    echo title Something
    echo set Character=%Character%
    echo set Name=%Name%
    echo set ID=%ID%
    echo set LV=%LV%
    echo set Money=%Money%
    echo set Rings=%Rings%
    echo set Weapons=%Weapons%
    echo set Armors=%Armors%
    echo set Runes=%Rings%
    echo set HP=%HP%
    echo set ATK=%ATK%
    echo set DEF=%DEF%
    echo set ArmorPen=%ArmorPen%
    echo set BaseDEF=%BaseDEF%
    echo set Heal=%Heal%
    echo set Gold=%Gold%
    echo set STAM=%STAM%
    echo set Mana=%Mana%
    echo set Spells=%Spells%
    echo set Counter=%Counter%
    echo Call Gruff2.bat
)
pause
Call blah.bat
```

Comment: Just above the answer text box are some formatting signs. They also give hints with their tooltips

Comment: Man cannot live on hugzies alone! By using my answer you have effectively accepted it in response to your question. I trust therefore that you will accept my answer appropriately such that I receive the appropriate site reward too.

Comment: Compo, I am single, and I give more to you than Just Hugzies and Kissies if you wish, if you want we can elope together and Raise a family together etc. ^_^